# Regex to capture google web fonts weights and styles

Tags: php, google-webfonts

Given a string in this form:

```
var myfont = 'Exo 2:600italic';
```

I need a regex to capture the numeric part of the string after the colon (600) as var1 and any value following the numeric value as var2.

For example, from the above string, I would get:

```
font-weight:600 //var1 value
font-style:italic //var2 value
```

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should work out for you:

```
:(?<var1>\d+)(?<var2>\w+)
```

This uses named groups (i.e. `(?<var1>` and `(?<var2>`) so the returned matches, if any, will be accessible via an associative array (with `var1` and `var2` as the array indexes).

Used with PHP's `preg_match()`:

```
$input = 'Exo 2:600italic';
$matches = array();
preg_match('/:(?<var1>\d+)(?<var2>\w+)/', $input, $matches);
```

Output:

```
print_r($matches);
Array (
    [0] => :600italic
    [var1] => 600
    [1] => 600
    [var2] => italic
    [2] => italic
)
```

If you want to directly access the values you're after, you can use:

```
$var1 = $matches['var1'];
$var2 = $matches['var2'];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to use what you've given me on the myfont string. Am I missing it? I just used var1 and var2 as placeholders to hold the weight and font style values from the myfont string.

Comment: @RegEdit I've updated my answer with sample use-cases for you

Comment: @AmalMurali Though the OP's questions says *any value following the numeric value*, in the end it's "up to the single-quote". It's not specified, but I'm pretty sure he may be parsing this directly in HTML - so you're right that `.*` would be a bad idea. Also, I don't really want to get into multi-character acceptance patterns, escaped quotes, etc - so, I will just leave it at `\w+` instead =]

Answer (score 1):

```
$myfont = 'Exo 2:600italic';

if (preg_match('~:(\d+)(\w+)~', $myfont, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => :600italic
    [1] => 600
    [2] => italic
)
```

To store the extracted values into new variables, you'd do:

```
$var1 = $matches[1];
$var2 = $matches[2];
```

Comment: @RegEdit: Glad to have been of help :)

Comment: Amal, when the input string is 'Exo 2:700', [1] is returning 70

Comment: @RegEdit: Is the text after the number optional? In that case, change the expression to `~:(\d+)(\w*)~`.